# How do i fix pattern ".env$" error while pushing commits to remote repo

Tags: reactjs, git, gitlab

I created a `.env`file with the following line `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` within my react app folder to get the app started on my localhost using `npm run start`. My 5 out of 6 commits contains the `.env` file. My last commit is the one where I deleted the .env file. i tried to push just that commit without `.env` file, yet it still shows the same error

```
todo1\t05-practical-work\backend>git push
Enumerating objects: 57, done.
Counting objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 6.58 KiB | 1.10 MiB/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: GitLab: File name frontend/.env was prohibited by the pattern ".env$".
To https://gitlab.tamk.cloud/courses/web-software-production-5g00dm04/3003/t05-practical-work.git
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.tamk.cloud/courses/web-software-production-5g00dm04/3003/t05-practical-work.git'
```

How can I fix it without losing my current branch and code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot push a commit without pushing its entire ancestry.

If you've set up your receiving repository to reject certain commits, you can't push those commits.  Since the sixth commit requires the earlier five commits that you already forbade to yourself, you can't push the sixth commit because you told yourself that this was forbidden.

Your options are:

- alter your forbidden-ness rules; or
- don't push those six commits, which means you can't push *any* of them.

To exercise the second option, consider taking the six commits and producing, from them, one *new and different* commit that *doesn't* do the forbidden thing.  This one new-and-different commit adds on to commits that are already accepted, and since this one commit won't do the thing your forbade to yourself, you won't reject your own commit.

To achieve this, the easy way is to use `git reset --soft HEAD~6` followed by `git commit`, or `git rebase -i HEAD~6` and turn five of the six commits into squash and/or fixup commits.